# How to add own fields to menu item in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i need to include my list area component in existing menu item(type: List All Categories) Administrator screen in Joomla

solution tried:
i have created new menu item type as component
its displaying my textarea now how can i load data input to the textarea
i have referred below link.
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_variable_request_in_the_menu_type.

Comment: To increase probability that you get answer to your question, describe what you have already tried and what was the problem with your approach. Also no need to email address - all answers should be posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created component referred below link and component type as overridden select-option, 
its working fine now.
Thanks

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_variable_request_in_the_menu_type